# Android app black screen after touch

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Ok i can replicate this all the time now with these steps:

Open the app then press back which takes me out the app.

Open the app up again and just after the splash page i get black screen and freezes.

On back press i call finish(); is this correct way to terminate the app? I can only assume something's not getting closed properly first time round and causing app not to load properly when i reopen it.

Anyone heard of this before?

Comment: On which version device you tested your application??

Comment: might ur testing on ICS.. put ur code so v can give u solution.. might threading problem..